# Fine-tune a BERT model for context specific embeddigns

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model

I'm trying to find information on how to train a BERT model, possibly from the [Huggingface Transformers](https://huggingface.co/transformers/index.html) library, so that the embedding it outputs are more closely related to the context o the text I'm using.

However, all the examples that I'm able to find, are about fine-tuning the model for another task, such as [classification](https://huggingface.co/transformers/training.html).

Would anyone happen to have an example of a BERT fine-tuning model for masked tokens or next sentence prediction, that outputs another raw BERT model that is fine-tuned to the context?

Thanks!

Comment: You can fine-tune BERT for Masked Language Model, which is unsupervised way of fine-tuning the system. https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertformaskedlm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example from the Transformers library on [Fine tuning a language model for masked token prediction](https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/examples/language_modeling.ipynb#scrollTo=a3KD3WXU3l-O).

The model that is used is one of the BERTForLM familly. The idea is to create a dataset using the [TextDataset](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/data/datasets/language_modeling.py) that tokenizes and breaks the text into chunks. Then use a [DataCollatorForLanguageModeling](https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/examples/language_modeling.ipynb#scrollTo=a3KD3WXU3l-O) to randomly mask tokens in the chunks when traing, and pass the model, the data and the collator to the [Trainer](https://huggingface.co/transformers/training.html#trainer) to train and evaluate the results.